# How to increase the height of listview?

Tags: android

In my application I am using a list view. I am using `ResourceCursorAdapter` and a custom layout design to populate values in the list view as two line list item from the database. The data is populating correctly but I need to increase the gap between the two textviews and also the height of the list view. [image]

Iam using the below code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_apiname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"        
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_apiurl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_apiname"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"        
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you wanna increase the height between two itemes of a listview? Show to the community your efforts with relevant snippet of code.

Comment: In other words: What have you tried? Nothing? Go try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >




     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_apiname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="jhf dnkldsklgkdfghngf"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_apiurl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_apiname"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
             android:text="jhf dnkldsklgkdfghngf"      
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the listview height to fill_parent to fill the whole view:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

To get some spacing between the text items, set some padding on them:

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

Or if you just want paddings in a certain direction:

```
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
```

... and so on.